# Particular class of time switching systems

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, control-theory, stability-in-odes

I am interested in understanding the behaviour of a class of continuous time switching systems of the form $\dot{x}(t) = f_{\sigma(t)}(x(t))$ where $f_{\bar{\sigma}}(x)$ is continuous for any $\bar{\sigma}$.

The particularity of this class of systems is that the switching rule $\sigma(t)$ is given by a piecewise constant function, where the intervals where it is constant have all the same length. Indeed, there is a time discretization $t_0<t_1<...<t_N=T$, where $\forall i\;\;\Delta t = t_{i+1} - t_i$ and $\sigma(t) = \lambda_i$ for $t\in [t_i,t_{i+1})$, $\lambda_i\in\{1,...,M\}$ a set of indices.

So the peculiarity is that the switching times are evenly spaced. Is this switching rule named in some way? Is there some reference where I can study it?

Comment: Maybe the search terms "minimal dwell time" might help you further.

Comment: Any discrete-to-analog converter does something like this, but I think that only in really "hard physics" simulations this would be modelled by ODE, otherwise the solution will be constructed from an approximate solution basis.

Comment: @LutzLehmann So you mean by a difference equation instead of a differential one?

Comment: No, I meant that you get a direct correspondence from $λ_i$ to the curve shape on the corresponding interval, disregarding or simplifying the transitions at the grid points. This will not cover the general situation, if the transitory effects last longer than the step size, you may get some mix where indeed difference equations can get involved.